# Page loading speeds, I'd like to understand more

Tags: performance, load, code-cleanup

The following question has been asked of me and I am keen to obtain as many opinions as possible:

Given a scenario where there are many drivers and a program that manages those drivers, there is a hypothetical top ten list. The list users metrics such as the number of journeys made and miles covered to rate the drivers. This list happens to be taking a long time to load (probably due to un-clean code), in peoples opinions where would the most likely bottlenecks occur?

Thanks for your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database - slow query
Alternatively it may be the application layer trying to fetch too many results.

Also if the results is to large you should consider caching the result and sharing across the different invocations.